# Lumen POST Routes not Working

Tags: lumen

Consider the following:

```
$router->group([
    'prefix' => 'api/v1/group',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
], function () use ($router) {

    $router->get('/', [
        'as'    => 'group.list',
        'uses'  => 'Api\V1\GroupController@list'
    ]);

    $router->post('/', [
        'as'    => 'group.create',
        'uses'  =>'Api\V1\GroupController@create'
    ]);

    $router->get('/{groupUUID}', [
        'as'    => 'group.retrieve',
        'uses'  =>'Api\V1\GroupController@retrieve'
    ]);

    $router->put('/{groupUUID}', [
        'as'    => 'group.update',
        'uses'  => 'Api\V1\GroupController@update'
    ]);


});
```

As you can see, a pretty typical route setup. However, I'm seeing some incredibly odd behaviour - in short, the `POST` route seems to be being interpreted by the app as a `GET` route. When I make a `POST` request to `api/v1/group` (via Postman) I don't see the result of `Api\V1\GroupController@create`, but the result of `Api\V1\GroupController@list`.

I wondered if perhaps this was something to do with both routes having the same endpoint (shouldn't matter, but maybe it's different in Lumen? I usually work in full-on Laravel). So I commented out the `get` route. That made me just see a 404.

I then wondered if perhaps this entire route group was somehow broken. So I made two catchall endpoints:

```
$router->get('/{any:.*}', function () use ($router) {
    return 'I am a get route';
});

$router->post('/{any:.*}', function () use ($router) {
    return 'I am a post route';
});
```

And placed them at the top of the routes file, and commented out all other routes. Regardless of the route I hit or the method used, I always saw the same thing: `I am a get route`.

What's going on? What could cause my app to understand all `POST` requests as `GET` requests?

PS: It's also worth noting that these routes *were* working, until recently, without any real associated changes. Could something have been updated in a Lumen package that caused this?

PPS: I also tried using Insomnia instead of Postman, just in case it was a problem with Postman. Same result.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: Which lumen version you are using.

Comment: I think, 1: Lumen is built for RESTful APIs and a POST request to the base route seems rather odd. You probably should try making a POST request to something that's more resource like e.g '/users' or something

Answer (score 0):

```
$router->get('/api/item/{table}/{id}', "ItemController@itemHandler");
$router->post('/api/item/{table}', "ItemController@itemHandler");
$router->put('/api/item/{table}/{id}', "ItemController@itemHandler");
$router->delete('/api/item/{table}/{id}', "ItemController@itemHandler");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same issue. In my case - since I use Laravel Valet as development environment - I was able to make a POST request again, after serving the API locally over HTTP by executing `valet unsecure my-project`. On my production server, I still can use HTTPS, but for my local development environment, this solved the issue. Hope this helps some future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try `api/v1/group/` (with trailing slash).